# I cannot apply Packages from Anaconda3 in my project interpreter in pycharm - why?

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm, anaconda

I Installed Pycharm and Anaconda3 to use packages like numpy, panda e.t.c
However, while I have all Anaconda packages now in my Project Interpreter (for default projects) I am not able to apply it. Can someone tell me why ? I am a bloody beginner. Thanks for any help  !

Comment: How did you install Anaconda and Python packages? Are you sure you chose correct Python interpreter in PyCharm's settings for current project?

Comment: 32 bit version and both latest visions available. Regarding to the interpreter I chose default project 3.6.0 (C:\Users\myname\Anaconda3\python.exe)

Comment: Thanks. Can you maybe elaborate what does it mean that you "cannot apply it" regarding Python interpreter in PyCharm? Does it show up in the list of your interpreters at all? If so, can't you just select it and save settings?

Comment: It shows up (like 100 other packages) and I can see the button "apply" but it is grey and shady and nothing happens when I click on it . Thanks for your interest so far.

Comment: Judging by your explanation, you selected the correct interpreter and you should be ready to go :) Can you share the screenshot of "Project Interpreter" screen from PyCharm preferences?

Comment: Screenshot (2).png

Comment: Update your original question with the screenshot :)

Comment: http://imageshack.com/a/img923/6045/lsUwnI.png

Comment: It seems that you chose right interpreter. Try to restart PyCharm and import your packages in that project and see if you will get any errors...

Comment: alright I will try

Comment: no I still cant apply it

Comment: Hm, how do you mean "apply it"? :) It seems to be applied... Go and write code now!!! :)

Comment: now I was able to click on the apply button (regarding to the screenshot in the bottom corner) but if I now try to import packages like numpy I get automatically an error.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Meiner/PycharmProjects/untitled/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

Comment: Check my answer and be 100% sure that you follow all the steps from the article properly :)

Comment: I did and it worked ... thank you!

Comment: Cool! :) Feel free to accept the answer than so that future users might solve problems like this... Happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure that you selected correct interpreter for **current project** (since every project can have a different interpreter). Check out [this PyCharm help article](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2017.1/configuring-python-interpreter-for-a-project.html) to make sure you are doing it correctly.